# How to Find TFS Changesets Not Linked to Work Items

Tags: tfs, tfs-sdk

Is there a way, either via a query or programmatically, to identify all TFS Changesets that are NOT linked to a Work Item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use the TFS API to do this very easily.

```
public static void GetAllChangesetsWithNoWorkItems()
{
    var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfs2010/tfs/default"));
    var service = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

    var histories = service.GetBranchHistory(new ItemSpec[] { new ItemSpec(@"$/ProjectName/MAIN/BUILD", RecursionType.OneLevel) }, VersionSpec.Latest);

    foreach (BranchHistoryTreeItem history in histories[0])
    {
        var change = service.GetChangeset(history.Relative.BranchToItem.ChangesetId, true, true);

        if(change.WorkItems.ToList().Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.Write(String.Format("Work Item Missing for Changeset {0}", change.ChangesetId));
        }
    }
}
```

You can read this blog post on how to connect to TFS API Programmatically http://geekswithblogs.net/TarunArora/archive/2011/06/18/tfs-2010-sdk-connecting-to-tfs-2010-programmaticallyndashpart-1.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Using the TFS PowerToy's PowerShell module:

From whatever folder in your workspace you're interested in:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory . -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.WorkItems.Length -eq 0 }
```

This will get the history for the current folder and all subfolders, and then filter for empty workitem lists.

Comment: See the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050689/how-do-i-set-up-tfs-powershell-snapin) if (like me) you don't know how to get the powershell addin working.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about [Richard's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6735632/57883) but the accepted answer took almost 2 minutes to run from the root of my team project collection. This runs in 10 seconds if you are looking for a specific user, 47 seconds if you aren't.

```
service.QueryHistory("$/TeamProject/", VersionSpec.Latest,0, RecursionType.Full,userName,null,null, Int32.MaxValue,true,false)
    .Cast<Changeset>()
    .Where(cs=>cs.AssociatedWorkItems.Length==0)
```

if you aren't looking for a specific user just set `userName` to null

http://share.linqpad.net/6sumno.linq